# What is index.php for?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand the dynamic web pages. Someone can explain to me what index.php is for?

What I understand is that based on `Title` or `Content`, the script inside that file makes a query to the database and generate a certain page.

Basically is it a file that redirects the user based on requests?

(I'm not sure it's a duplicate, but checking i found nothing)

Comment: At its most basic, `index.php` is the first file that will show up when a browser goes to the site or a directory. Beyond that, it can be used for whatever the site/project dictates. For more complicated sites or frameworks, it acts as the "boot" script.

Comment: https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/Index/php-index-function-examples.html;
@aynber In the first example what does that script do?

Comment: Hurt my poor little brain because it's so outdated it's using mysql_* functions. It uses 2 functions that aren't defined in the script, so you can only guess at what `check_url()` and `add_page()` do.

Comment: `index.php` is just like `foobar.php` or any other PHP script, except it's typically loaded as the default page, like `index.html`. Your `index.php` can be `<?php echo 'Hello World!';` or anything else you care to do with PHP. It can also be `<?php $_GET['page'] ??= 'default'; if($_GET['page'] == 'hello') { echo "<b>Hello</b>"; } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 'world') { echo "<i>Earth</i>"; } else { echo "Default Planet"; }` for example.

Comment: @aynber Ahahah, I'm sorry. In any case, I would need to understand in more detail what it does. I am programming a web server in python inspired by apache and dynamic sites.
For example, on wikipedia the registration section is https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CreateAccount&returnto=xxx. I assumed that the index parses Title and based on it takes a "create account" page from the database.

Comment: If you're talking about setups where it's called in browser e.g. as `index.php?page=foo` or `?page=bar`, your `index.php` basically **1.** parses user input ie. the `$_GET` query string, then **2.** loads related data/resources from database or otherwise, finally **3.** compiles the output and blurts it out. These aspects are commonly called MVC (Model-View-Controller), here in order of C-M-V for simple page requests. (You should really not stuff a full MVC setup into your `index.php` though, except for the simplest of things, but rather call further code from other files.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's divide the answer into **two parts** :

1. What is a dynamic page ?
2. What is Index.php & Why it's called Index and the usage of it ?

**First,** Dynamic pages are the pages that changes from time to time and/or from user to another and/or from location to another, they are the opposite of static pages (example of static pages: landing pages or resume page).

**Second,** When you type into URL bar in your browser "facebook.com" you are accessing a very generic location, Imagine opening Drive C on windows you will find many folders shown with different names, hence we cannot show file structure of the web server to users who are accessing the website and we want to solve this problem where we want users to access specific location, so developers decided to make a default home page which called "Index" another example when you open the book first you go to Index page to know the content of each page and which one to read. In general any website (websitename.com) will redirect you automatically to index file (websitename.com/index.php),

Thus the link of Facebook should look like this :

- [**Home page**] [facebook.com/index.php](https://facebook.com/index.php) or [facebook.com/home.php](https://facebook.com/home.php) (if logged-in)
- [**Login page**] [facebook.com/login.php](https://facebook.com/login.php)